# How to use selenium webdriver to select an option of Bootstrap select dropdown menu?

Tags: select, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, bootstrapping

I've to select a country from dropdown of https://www.parcelhero.com but when I use the below code for it, sometimes it works sometimes not, giving error of Element not found(xpath("//*[@id='dvQuoteFrom']/div/button"))

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvQuoteFrom']/div/button")).click();

        Thread.sleep(4000);

       WebElement txt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[14]/div/div/input"));
txt.sendKeys("Great Britain");
List <WebElement> InnerDropdown1 =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='active']"));
       for(WebElement option1 :  InnerDropdown1)
        {   System.out.println(option1.getText());

        if(option1.getText().contains("Great Britain")) {
          option1.click();
           break; 
       }
        }
```

When I used 
WebElement txt = driver.findElement(By.className("bs-searchbox")); then also I got the uable to find element error.

Please help me to select a country of my choice from the country dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. I've changed a few of your locators and tested this on the page you mentioned.

```
public void foo() {
    driver.get("https://www.parcelhero.com/");

    //This will be your dropdown button. This needs to be clicked first.
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@data-id,'ConsignorAddressCountryId')]")).click();

    //These are your input boxes. I found 3 input boxes on the same page having the same identifiers. We dont want to rely on using index based xpath so here we'll get all instances of input boxes.
    List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'bs-searchbox')]//input"));
    for (WebElement elem : elems) {

        //Here we check if the input box is visible. If I'm not mistaken, there will only be 1 visible input box at a time because you have to click on the dropdown button first.
        if (elem.isDisplayed()) {
            //If visible, just enter your country of choice
            elem.sendKeys("American Samoa");
            //Assuming you always enter exact match string for your test, you can use the org.openqa.selenium.Keys for sendKeys()
            elem.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it